# what's the difference between "I know." and " I know that."?

Tags: emphasis

example dialog:

> "yes, yes, it's your job. ***I know that.***"

Can I just say "I know" instead of "I know that"?

another one: do I say

> It is very pretty.  Where did you ***buy?***
>    -or-
>   where did you ***buy it?***

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can say "I know" *or* "I know that.
 (2) You really need the "it' here.  "Where did you buy?" sounds incomplete, leading to another question, "Where did I buy *what*?"

I think the difference may be that in sentence 2, you're referring to a thing, so the "it" is standing in for whatever was bought, while in question 1 "it's your job" is an abstraction, so somehow it's OK to just say, "I know."

Comment: _Know_ in (1) refers to the clause that comes right before it, so there's no pronoun necessary -- it's essentially a transform of _I know it's your job_. In (2), however, the object of _know_ is not indicated, as you point out, so something must be provided.

Comment: I agree with David.

Comment: My answer may be correct in saying that "that" is needed in one sentence and not in the other, but John Lawler analyzed and explained the difference.

Comment: One sentence," John is reading a book.Where did he get?" Can I omit the pronoun "it" because" a book" is just right before "Where did he get?"

Comment: No, that sounds wrong.  I see your point: you've just mentioned the book, so what else could "get" be referring to?  But you need to say "Where did he get it?", where the pronoun "it" is standing in for "the book".

Answer (score 0):

In dialog, you would usually say "I know that" as a simple statement. "I know" would be accompanied either by a gesture such as holding up your hand with the palm toward the other person to signify that he doesn't need to say any more, or by significant stress on the words to send the same message.

This may not apply outside the US.